# React Native: Re-Render Component When Tab is Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation and am trying to force a re-render of a component (and a `getData()` function) when I click on the tab.

I tried to follow [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1171) but no luck.

**Router**

```
export const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  {
  Progress: {
    screen: ProgressStack,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'Progress',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
      <Icon name="trending-up" size={25} color={tintColor} />
    }),
  },
export const ProgressStack = StackNavigator({
  Progress: {
    screen: ProgressScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Progress',
    }),
  },
});
```

**Progress Component**

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
  console.log('rerender!');
  this.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not something i've tried, but I think this might be the right approach: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/with-navigation-focus.html

Use that high order component to pass a `isFocusedProp` then use `componentDidUpdate` to call `getData`

```
componentDidUpdate (previousProps) {
  if (!previousProps.isFocused && this.props.isFocused) {
    this.getData()
  }
}
```

There is also an onPress button event you can use: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress, but that would require a way to trigger the data call you're doing. If you're using redux, you would need to pass dispatch or the bound action function through the route params.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Do I need to make any amendments to my `Router` using this solution or simply drop in the lifecycle method you've included? (And i'm unfortunately not using Redux at the moment).

Comment: No Router changes should be necessary. Just where you export Progress: `export default withNavigationFocus(Progress)`. and then check for that prop as i described above. This has no dependencies on redux to work :)